# Selecting masked objects

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools, masking

I am making animations for a zombie and using mask modifiers on different body parts which are separate models to hide in the renderer, however once a full piece of geometry is hidden i am no longer able to select it anywhere to turn the mask off again.. is there any way to select hidden geometry so i can disable the modifier and allowing it to render again?   hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You can see anything in your scene in the outliner.
[image]